# Вызвать событие основного скрипта из WebExtension для Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Я создал простое расширение для Firefox, которое на определенном сайте автоматически заполняет `<input type="text">` посредством кода:

```js
var dt = document.getElementById("dfTime");
dt.value = "test";
$(dt).trigger("change");
```

Обработка события изменения данного `<input type="text">` на сайте происходит внутри модуля DBEdit.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
...
export class DBEdit extends DSElements{
constructor(node){
...
this.on('change', evnt => this.doChange(evnt));
...
}
...
async doChange(evnt){
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    let _target = evnt.target;
    if(this._oldVal !== _target.value){
        if(this.doValidate(false)){
            this.bEdited = this.bEdited || (this._oldVal !== this.value);
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

После успешной вставки данных через мой скрипт в расширении никаких событий не вызывается. Использование `$(dt).trigger("change");` не приводит к нужному результату (события модуля DBEdit.js не срабатывают).

**Каким образом я могу вызвать на странице сайта событие change/input/paste/keydown для данного input?**

Пробовал запускать в скрипте расширения через `window.eval('var dt = document.getElementById("dfTime"); $(dt).trigger("change");');`, не помогло.

jQuery в расширении подключен и работает.

Изменять код сайта возможности нет (он не мой).